# CString extract file path

Tags: c++, find

Hey I'm trying to extract the file path but the problem is that I'm stuck in an infinite loop don't understand why. Please have a look at my code.

```
CString myString(_T("C:\\Documents and Settings\\admin\\Desktop\\Elite\\Elite\\IvrEngine\\dxxxB1C1.log"));

int pos = myString.Find(_T("\\"));

while (pos != -1)
{
    pos = myString.Find(_T("\\"), pos); // it keeps returning 2
}

CString folderPath = myString.Mid(pos);
```

Now the problem is that, Find() returns 2 the first time I run, but then in the while loop it keeps returning 2, why is the function unable to find the rest **'\'** ? So now I'm in an infinite loop :(.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like `Find` includes the character at the position you give it when searching. So if you give it the position of a character that matches the search, then it will return that same position.

You probably need to change it to:

```
pos = myString.Find(_T("\\"), pos + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

your code will never work! When the while loop finished, the contend of pos can not be used.
Here is a solution which will work:

```
CString folderPath;
int pos = myString.ReverseFind('\\');
if (pos != -1)
{
    folderPath = myString.Left(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`CString::Find` always returns the first occurence of the character you're searching for. So it keeps finding the the first `"\\"` which is at index 2 infinitely since you're searching from 2 which includes that `"\\"`

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the code (see the pos + 1 answers) but I think that you should use [`_splitpath_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e46eyt7(VS.80).aspx) instead which was intended for this kind of operations.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand your initial implementation, as the behaviour of CString::Find() seem to have changed over time.

Take a look at the MSDN docs for MFC implementation shipped with VC6 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314323%28VS.60%29.aspx) and at the current implementation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hz2099kw%28VS.80%29.aspx). Especially look at the differences of the description of the 2nd offset parameter.

The solution to your problem is, as already stated above, to add 1 to the search offset of the successive Find() calls. You can also search for single chars (or wchar_ts) like that:

```
myString.Find(_T('\\'), pos+1);
```

EDIT:

BTW, take a look at the [Path*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773559%28VS.85%29.aspx) familly of functions exposed by the shlwapi.dll, declared in shlwapi.h. Especially the [PathRemoveFileSpec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773748%28VS.85%29.aspx) function might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

in MFC, example to get folder which including executable file:

```
char ownPth[MAX_PATH]; 

// Will contain exe path
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
if(NULL == hModule){
    return __LINE__;
}

// When passing NULL to GetModuleHandle, it returns handle of exe itself
GetModuleFileName(hModule,ownPth, (sizeof(ownPth))); 
modulePath = (LPCSTR)ownPth;
modulePath = modulePath.Left(modulePath.ReverseFind(_T('\\')));

return 0;
```